# Problema con Django y Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-3.x, django

estoy tratando de utilizar un elemento de un plantilla para mostrar una alerta de error con Ajax, tengo la siguiente función de JavaScript:

```
function message_error(obj){
 var html = '<ul>';
 $.each(obj,function(key, value){
     html+='<li>'+key+': '+value+'</li>';
 });
 html+='</ul>';
}
```

Y lo mando llamar mediante Ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
var parameters = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'sistema:add' %}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            if(!data.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                location.href = '{{ list_url }}';
                return false;
            }
            message_error(data.error);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            alert(textStatus+': '+errorThrown)
        }).always(function(data){
    });
```

Esa función en lugar de mostrarla en consola quisiera mostrarla dentro del siguiente código:

```
<div class="card-body">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ action }}">
{% if form.errors %}
    <div id="alert-AdminLTE" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Ha ocurrido un error al guardar el registro</h5>
        <ul>
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <li> {{ error }} </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<div class="form-group">
```

Pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, al darle guardar simplemente retorna el mensaje en una página nueva en blanco. Algún consejo de que hacer para que funcione